# How to use onelogin SSO with AngularJS?

Tags: saml, onelogin

I was looking into [Onelogin](https://developers.onelogin.com/) for SSO. We have applications written in .NET, AngularJS + Node. None of these applications are mobile applications. After going through their documentation I have few questions:

1> Onelogin is using SAML instead of OpenID Connect. I am not asking what's the difference between these two, but what is recommended since everyone is moving towards OpenID Connect?

2> Does Onelogin supports AngularJS? I don't see any documentation for onelogin API with AngularJS & Node [See Here](https://developers.onelogin.com/saml)

Answer (score 2):

Know this is old, but for the sake of completeness, OneLogin has added an AngularJS example that can be found at [github](https://github.com/onelogin/onelogin-oidc-angular).

There are other examples available as well, [found here](https://github.com/onelogin/onelogin-oidc-node)